# Adding a where clause to a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, where-clause

I'm looking to add a `WHERE` clause to the trigger shown below and looking for a bit of advice if possible. Currently the trigger works on the basis of any particular items being added to the order and not just specific ones (ideally with a prefix).

```
CREATE TRIGGER ItalianEmail ON SOPOrderReturn
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    declare @SOPOrderReturnID int;

    UPDATE SOPOrderReturn
    SET AnalysisCode19 = 'mario@aol.com'
    FROM SOPOrderReturn
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON SOPOrderReturn.SOPOrderReturnID = i.SOPOrderReturnID)
GO
```

The layout of the tables in SQL Server is the following:

- `SOPOrderReturn` [Header Table] -- Holds Order Information (has primary key `SOPOrderReturnID`)
- `SOPOrderReturnLine` [Order Line table] -- stores the item data for the order
  (has primary key `SOPOrderReurnLineID` and a foreign key `SOPOrderReturnID`)

I need the `WHERE` clause to pick up the `StockItem` on the `SOPOrderReturnLine` table if its `LIKE 'XXX_%'`

I hope I have explained enough of the structure of the tables for you to get an idea of what I would like to achieve?

Any help offered is gratefully appreciated and I thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure what StockItem means here. Are you trying to limit which rows in SOPOrderReturn are getting updated? If so, why not just add your where clause to the query?

Comment: Hi Sean, Correct about the StockItem. I want to limit where there is a specific stock Item Matches a Like Query. However I'm not exactly sure if I need another INNER JOIN to Linke to the SOPOrderReturn Table to the SOPOrderReturnLine table (where the stockItem is located)

Comment: How would we know? We have no clue what that means. You seem to be wanting to evaluate the value of some column but you didn't share that piece of information so there is really not much we can do.

Comment: Might be worth looking at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I shall take that on board.

Comment: Yes you can add a WHERE clause to the update command in your trigger.    Will it do what you want?   Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Notice the alias on

```
CREATE TRIGGER ItalianEmail ON SOPOrderReturn
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    declare @SOPOrderReturnID int;

    UPDATE oRet
    SET AnalysisCode19 = 'mario@aol.com'
    FROM SOPOrderReturn oRet
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON (oRet.SOPOrderReturnID = i.SOPOrderReturnID)
    INNER JOIN SOPOrderReturnLine oRetLine ON (oRetLine.SOPOrderReturnID = i.SOPOrderReturnID)
    WHERE oRetLine.StockItem LIKE 'XXX%'

GO
```